# How to get MAMP to read .htaccess files

Tags: .htaccess, mamp

I am trying to get the `.htaccess` working in MAMP. The content of the `.htaccess` is a simple redirect line, but the entire .htaccess file seems to have no effect, even when I change it to contain invalid data.

Is there any settings within MAMP I need to change to enable `.htaccess` files?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Go to `httpd.conf` on `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache` and see if the `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` line is un-commented (without the # at the beginning)

and change these
 from   ...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ...
    DocumentRoot /....
</VirtualHost>
```

To this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin ...
    ServerName ...

    DocumentRoot ...
    <Directory ...>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory ...>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 103):

1. In `httpd.conf` on `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache`, find:

   ```
   <Directory />
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
   </Directory>
   ```
2. Replace `None` with `All`.
3. Restart MAMP servers.

Comment: Thank you! Every other comment I found about this issue had to do with updating permalinks, and I knew that wasn't my problem. This solved it!

Comment: for debugging, immediately check if your .htaccess file is consulted, at all.  the easiest way to do this is to place garbage into it.  this should give a '500 server error'.   Then proceed to put in what you really want.  (Also, in the <Directory> directive, you may want a `RewriteEngine On`)

Comment: Great solution. I tried all the other suggestions starting with simply saving the permalink setting in WP. Then was lead here and this solution worked.

Comment: Thanks! This was really odd. I upgraded to MAMP 4.2 a few days ago and everything was working fine. Then I revisited today after a few days and it didn't work anymore. This solved it, but I have no idea how the MAMP httpd.conf file could have changed between then and now as I haven't touched this project or MAMP since it was working.

Comment: Great! Watch out in httpd.conf because there are a few similar lines. In MAMP 4 its the line under "# First, we configure the "default" to be a very restrictive set of # features." :)

Comment: This appears to be a thing, with CraftCMS and MAMP, in 2021. Thanks for the answer, will report back if there is a cleaner way without changing a low level MAMP file.

Answer (score 7):

I'm using MAMP (downloaded today) and had this problem also. The issue is with this version of the MAMP stack's default httpd.conf directive around line 370. Look at httpd.conf down at around line 370 and you will find:

```
<Directory "/Applications/MAMP/bin/mamp">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

You need to change:     AllowOverride None
To:                     AllowOverride All

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me - I guess because I am using authentication

Answer (score 5):

If you have MAMP PRO you can set up a host like mysite.local, then add some options from the 'Advanced' panel in the main window. Just switch on the options 'Indexes' and 'MultiViews'. 'Includes' and 'FollowSymLinks' should already be checked.

Comment: Thanks...it looks like MAMP PRO has updated and these checkboxes are now on the `Hosts` page, under the `Extended` tab

Answer (score 5):

The problem I was having with the rewrite is that some .htaccess files for Codeigniter, etc come with

```
RewriteBase /
```

Which doesn't seem to work in MAMP...at least for me.

Comment: What should I use instead of /? I'm having a similar issue with an htaccess file, but modrewrite works for other projects on my localhost.

Comment: Commenting out the `RewriteBase` would be a solution to specific things within .htaccess not working, but not a solution to .htaccess not being read at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have MAMP v 6.6.2 (year 2022), and I was trying to make working ***php friendly URLs*** on my localhost Apache, by adding '.htaccess' file to my website root directory ("**localhost/mywebsite/.htaccess**"):

```
RewriteEngine On   
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Which didn't work. But I tested it on cPanel hosting on a real domain and it worked fine.

So I have tried to change httpd.conf with these advises:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21411933/3936149 - didn't help
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7670598/3936149 - didn't help
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19204983/3936149 - didn't help

In the end I came up to an advise:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/16106140/3936149 - and it worked!

I simply commented out the second line of the code in my '.htaccess' (located at "**localhost/mywebsite/.htaccess**") file and that's it:

```
RewriteEngine On   
# RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

After it started to work I reverted all the changes in ***httpd.conf*** file, I have done above, and it was still working.