# Fixing an htaccess 404 not found issue

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, localhost, mamp, mamp-pro

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting a 404 Not Found issue.

The requested URL /welcome was not found on this server.

I am running on a localserver with Mamp Pro. I set up a new server on port 80 with dev.mysite.com and have it pointed to the correct file path for the document root.

Is there any settings within the server on Mamp Pro I need to set up for that server.

```
- Sites
    - mysite
      - application
          - controllers
              welcome.php
      - public_html (document root)
          index.php
          - assets
      - system
```

When I load the welcome controller with the following link I get the welcome controller successfully.

```
dev.mysite.com/index.php/welcome
```

When I go to the following link I get a 404 Not Found error because it can't the requested URL on the server.

Here is what I'm using for a .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on



#remove index from url

#RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets)

#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]



# Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]



#Block bad bots

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BlackWidow [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Bot\ mailto:craftbot@yahoo.com [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ChinaClaw [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Custo [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^DISCo [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Download\ Demon [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^eCatch [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EirGrabber [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailSiphon [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailWolf [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Express\ WebPictures [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ExtractorPro [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EyeNetIE [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^FlashGet [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetRight [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetWeb! [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go!Zilla [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go-Ahead-Got-It [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GrabNet [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Grafula [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^HMView [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} HTTrack [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Stripper [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Sucker [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Indy\ Library [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^InterGET [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Internet\ Ninja [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JetCar [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JOC\ Web\ Spider [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^larbin [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^LeechFTP [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mass\ Downloader [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^MIDown\ tool [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mister\ PiX [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Navroad [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NearSite [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetAnts [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetSpider [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Net\ Vampire [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetZIP [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Octopus [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Explorer [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Navigator [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^PageGrabber [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Papa\ Foto [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pavuk [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pcBrowser [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^RealDownload [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ReGet [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SiteSnagger [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SmartDownload [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperBot [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperHTTP [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Surfbot [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^tAkeOut [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Teleport\ Pro [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^VoidEYE [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Image\ Collector [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Sucker [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebAuto [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebCopier [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebFetch [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebGo\ IS [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebLeacher [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebReaper [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebSauger [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ eXtractor [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ Quester [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebStripper [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebWhacker [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebZIP [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Wget [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Widow [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WWWOFFLE [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Xaldon\ WebSpider [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Zeus

RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]



#Prevent viewing of .htaccess file

<Files .htaccess>

order allow,deny

deny from all

</Files>



#Prevent directory listings

Options All -Indexes
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get htaccess to work on MAMP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670561/how-to-get-htaccess-to-work-on-mamp)

Comment: I'd say look into.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670561/how-to-get-htaccess-to-work-on-mamp first, see if its enabled/configured to be used