# Laravel 4 on MAMP won't work without index.php in URL

Tags: .htaccess, laravel

Since updating my virtual host so I can view my app at dev.mysite.com instead of the previous localhost/mysite/public, I cannot get the app to have 'pretty urls'.

It will only work if I use dev.mysite.com/index.php/register

How can I revise my settings so I can view at dev.mysite.com/register

HTACCESS

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

ROUTES.PHP

```
Route::get('register', array('uses' => 'UserController@create'));
```

HTTPD-VHOSTS.CONF

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/public"
    ServerName dev.mysite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Firstly you've got `RewriteEngine On` twice in your .htaccess remove the second one. If it still doesn't work try adding `RewriteBase /` just after the first `RewriteEngine On`

Comment: Have tried both, but unfortunately makes no difference.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670561/how-to-get-htaccess-to-work-on-mamp might help

Comment: beech, that's helped me find a solution

<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
</Directory>