# How to reach Laravel without /public/index.php

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm following the official Laravel course (currently the first chapter "[Meet Composer](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/1),"), but I can't seem to get it right. In the course I was instructed to enter in the command line:

```
php -S localhost:8888 -t public
```

and I should be able to reach the URL: "http://localhost:8888/learning-laravel-5", but this gives me a 404 error.

But if I put in this URL I get to see the frontpage, as it should: http://localhost:8080/learning-laravel-5/public/index.php

My question is, how can I see the frontpage as instructed in the video, following the provided URL: http://localhost:8888/learning-laravel-5 ?

I have looked through the duplicate questions on stackoverflow but I can't find a solution to this problem.

Edit:  I have tried to get my absolute path by doing pwd, its says "/media/sf_sandbox/laracast-4.2", I now have done this: "php -S localhost:8888 -t /media/sf_sandbox/laracast-4.2/public". I now go to localhost:8888  but it still doesn't work.

It says my documentroot is /media/sf_sandbox/learning-laravel-5/public

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running below command from the project root `learning-laravel-5` , than `localhost:8888`
it self points to the `learning-laravel-5/public` folder

```
php -S localhost:8888 -t /var/www/html/learning-laravel-5/public
```

In this case only `localhost:8888` should work and you don't need to append `learning-laravel-5` after that.

Comment: Sorry @pinkal, this does not work for me, I typed "php -S localhost:8888 -t public", I got a response with "Listening on http://localhost:8888" but when I go to http://localhost:8888/ I just see that the page isn't available.

Comment: @Joop Try absolute path. I have Updated my answer.

Comment: Hi @pinkal, I have tried to get my absolute path by doing pwd, its says "/media/sf_sandbox/laracast-4.2", I now have done this: "php -S localhost:8888 -t /media/sf_sandbox/laracast-4.2/public". I now go to http://localhost:8888/ and still nothing happens, though it says it's listening to the url localhost:8888. I'm really wondering what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using XAMP..because 
For XAMP, localhost port is 8000 And
For XAMP, localhost port is 8000.

in the laravel directory, where you ran composer, type `php artisan serve`. This will run an internal webserver, which opens up 8000 port by default. Once you have that, open your browser and access http://localhost:8000

If that works, you have an issue with your MAMP configuration.

If it is MAMP, check the following

**1)** make sure you set the document root to the /public directory in your laravel installation.

**2**
make sure you have enabled rewrite module in your mamp.

Checkout [How to get htaccess to work on MAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670561/how-to-get-htaccess-to-work-on-mamp)

Comment: I'm not using any of those packages, I have a Ubuntu virtualbox LAMP running. To add: I'm using port 8080, and I want to use 8888, not 8000 as you specified.