# How to have the .htaccess with Mamp

Tags: php, .htaccess, mamp

How to have the .htaccess in a local environment and Mamp?

I have in Applications > Mamp > htdocs > myWebsite this 2 files:
index.php
.htaccess

In .htaccess I have:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /myWebsite/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

If i write this in the browser, it works:
http://localhost/myWebsite/index.php

But if I write this does not:
http://localhost/myWebsite/index
This means that the .htacces does not take effect, I suppose.

I have searched a lot of places and applied what they say. Just an example:
[How to get htaccess to work on MAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670561/how-to-get-htaccess-to-work-on-mamp)

```
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

Replace None with All
Restart MAMP servers

I have checked to upload that files in a remote server and there, it works well.

What else can I do? how to have the .htaccess with Mamp?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set AllowOverride to ALL in the settings of the individual host.

Peter