# How to correctly activate mod_rewrite mamp?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite, mamp

The local wordpress website home page runs well but `mod_rewrite` does not work. So, the home page works, but as soon as I click any link I get `Not Found`.

Log output for this error:

```
[error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myweb/my-web-page-that-has-to-work, referer: http://myweb.dev/
```

As per my understanding, the error would mean that it looks for that specific page instead of using `mod_rewrite` in order tot get the page from database.

`httpd.conf` relevant content:

```
# Virtual hosts, uncommented include
Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

...

# AllowOverride All is here
<Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs">
Options All
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
XSendFilePath "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"
</Directory>
```

`httpd-vhosts.conf` relevant content:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myweb"
ServerName myweb.dev
ServerAlias www.myweb.dev
ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/myweb-error_log"
CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/myweb-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Any clue on how to get it to work?

Answer (score 4):

First make sure Apache loads the module. See: [How to enable mod_rewrite for Apache 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2)

Then add this to an .htaccess file inside your folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
</IfModule>
```

or just add it to your httpd-vhosts.conf like this. **CORRECTED:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myweb"
  ServerName myweb.dev
  ServerAlias www.myweb.dev
  ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/myweb-error_log"
  CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/myweb-access_log" common


  <Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myweb">
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all  

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
           RewriteEngine On
           RewriteBase /
        </IfModule>

  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Now add your rewrite rules for WP and see if it works.

You may check if Apache is loading the module with a PHP script inside your folder. Try this and proceed from there.

```
<?php

if (in_array('mod_rewrite', apache_get_modules())) {
    echo "Yes, Apache supports mod_rewrite.";
}

else {
    echo "Apache is not loading mod_rewrite.";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I use MAMP, which is for osx, and there is no such thing as `a2enmod` . also I tried to put the `IfModule` there, but the Apache Server won't start.

Comment: Have you tried to just add **RewriteEngine On** and **AllowOverride All** to your Virtualhost.

Comment: server won't start. Only works when I remove the lines

Comment: Remove the <ifModule ...> tag. Also this is how you [add the module in MAMP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670561/how-to-get-htaccess-to-work-on-mamp).

Comment: I did, the server starts but no change, still not found.

Comment: I think the module is not loaded check the changes above.

Comment: `Yes, Apache supports mod_rewrite.` also I update the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file, and still get not found

Answer (score 0):

1. First make sure MAMP Apache loads the module. MAMP has activated this by default.
2. I made this for Joomla. Wordpress should be similar. Mac would not allow you to rename the htaccess.txt in the root (htdocs/yourwebsite/)
3. Instead of playing with Addons that show hidden files - the easiest way is to open Filezilla and rename the local file there. You use the usual wordpress htaccess and rename it to .htaccess
4. Activeate rewrite as usual in the wordpress-backend.