# Codeigniter 404 Page Not Found

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am new to Codeigniter.

my db controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Dbview extends CI_Controller{
        public function index()
        //standard SQL Query
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM 'news'",
        $data['query_sql'] = $this->db->query($sql);
        //active record query
        $data['query_ar'] = $this->db->get('news');
        //load view
        $this->load->view('dbview',$data);}
?>
```

my dbview in view

## DB Test

```
<br />
<b>Standard SQL Query</b> <pre><?php print_r($query_sql->result_array()); ?>></pre>
<br />
<b>Active Record Query</b> <pre><?php print_r($query_ar->result_array()); ?></pre>
```

I set up database in phpmyadmin, and put the database info into config/database
when I try to open the browser http://localhost/WeatherFinder/index.php/dbview
nothing is opening. whats wrong or what else I haven't done?
Thx

Comment: if its a completely white screen, double check your database settings are correct, maybe post them here.

Comment: Is your filename Dbview.php only first letter must be uppercase explained here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming and also you don't need to close controller https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#php-closing-tag

Comment: @coderodour, Its not white, its 404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 I changed it to lowercase, still not working

Comment: also ensure apache rewrite module is enabled. You can accomplish this by issuing `sudo a2enmod rewrite` from command line in ubuntu.

Comment: @coderodour my setting is  $config['index_page'] = "index.php" , I just tried $config['index_page'] = "", still not working

Comment: @coderodour I am using MAMP

Comment: @coderodour   have .htaccess at root
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: @J.J I said upper case not lower case.

Comment: @wolfgang1983  oh sorry, my file name is Dbview.php. only the first letter is uppercase

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have found your issue. You are missing an opening curly brace for your index function, as pointed out and corrected in the code below.

```
<?php
  defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

  class Dbview extends CI_Controller{

    public function index(){ // --- This opening brace missing maybe the issue.

      //standard SQL Query
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM 'news'",
      $data['query_sql'] = $this->db->query($sql);

      //active record query
      $data['query_ar'] = $this->db->get('news');

      //load view
      $this->load->view('dbview',$data);
    }
}
```

You do not need to and are discouraged from closing your controllers with a `?>`.

Comment: My code above had some shortcomings, should be working now.

Comment: try to follow the suggestions in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670561/how-to-get-htaccess-to-work-on-mamp)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for everyone trying to help!
I think that I may found the problem. 
Its is in my model file, I haven't wrote it properly. 
I will try to fix it later.
and keep you posted!