# How to Clone Laravel Project and Run on Mamp

Tags: php, laravel, mamp

I have an existing Laravel project I want to clone from GitHub.

I normally run Laravel on Homestead/Vagrant.

But this time I need to run it on Mamp.

I already cloned the project into my htdocs folder.

When I click to see my website, I see Index of/ then all the files.

**Index of/**

.env.example

.git/

.gitattributes

.gitignore

.phpintel/

app/

artisan

bootstrap/

composer.json

composer.lock

config/

database/

gulpfile.js

package.json

phpunit.xml

public/

readme.md

resources/

scratch3.php

server.php

storage/

tests/

What do I need to do/change/configure so my Laravel website works properly.

I'm on a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

According to my experience, there are some steps for setting up an existing Laravel project as follows:

1. Install PHP and Composer
2. In your Laravel dir, run `composer install`
3. Then copy `.env.example` file to `.env`
4. Open `.env` and change a database connection information and save file
5. Generate the application key by using a command `php artisan key:generate`
6. Run a migration if exist by using a command `php artisan migrate`
7. Then run `composer dump-autoload`
8. Finally, start your project with command `php artisan serve` or create a shortcut in a `public` directory or Mamp and link it to public folder of your Laravel project.

Hope this helps, any comment is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

if you click your website and you see your root you probably need to configure your settings a bit, maybe this will help
[How to get htaccess to work on MAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670561/how-to-get-htaccess-to-work-on-mamp)