# BrowserRouter wordpress react routing

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, react-router

I am trying to route to a component in react from a component which is rendered on a wordpress page. Search Now `Link` below is the link that is rendered on a wordpress page from a component and I am trying to get to `PageFetch`  component when clicking Search Now . But when I click , I see only url changing in browser to `/wordpress/search` but it does not go anywhere . There is no error in console and I don't see `console.log` statement that I have in `PageFetch` component.

```
const HomePageFlightContainer  = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
        ....
    <div className="col-lg-3">                    
                          <Link to="/wordpress/search" className="theme-btn w-100 text-center margin-top-20px">
                          Search Now
                        </Link>                    
            
                      </div>
          ....
          </Router>
      );
}
```

This is my react index.js

```
import HomePageFlightContainer from './HomePageFlightContainer';
import PageFetch from './PageFetch';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Router >
            
                <Switch>
                   <Route  path="/" component={HomePageFlightContainer} />
                    <Route  path="/wordpress/search" component={PageFetch} />
                </Switch>
            
        </Router>
    );
};

export default App;
ReactDOM.render(<HomePageFlightContainer />, document.getElementById('search-flights-container'));
```

And below is my PageFetch component (where I would like to go after click)

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const PageFetch = (slug) => {
    const [pageContent, setPageContent] = useState('');
          console.log("response content:::", page.content)
           ... //get wordpress page here through axios
            });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Search Page</h1>
            {loading ? (
                <p>Loading...</p>
            ) : (
                <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: pageContent }} />
            )}
        </div>
    );
};    
export default PageFetch;
```

I also came across that I  will need to add rewrite rule in .htaccess file. So I checked and I already had below content in .htaccess . And I have also tried commenting `# RewriteBase /wordpress/` line in .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
# RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

and changing `AllowOverride None`  to

```
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670561/how-to-get-mamp-to-read-htaccess-files)

How do I make react routing work for wordpress ?

**EDIT**
As per suggestion below , I am editing to include more information

I have a wordpress site that loads a not react homepage.php ,which Included a "Search Now" button ( code below)that when clicked was going to result page and I was diaplaying results on result page using React. Uptil now everything was fine

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
                            <a
                              href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'flight-search-result' ) ); ?>"
                              class="theme-btn w-100 text-center margin-top-20px" onclick="FrontPage.setValuesForExtendedSearch()"
                              >Search Now</a
                            >
                          </div>
```

Now I wanted to display some information from external api  below this "Search Now" button based on what user is searching. So I thought of React solution but "Search Now" container is rendered non react way (as mentioned earlier), So I changed that container to be rendered through React, which worked. But the problem now is to go to search result page from this react rendered "Search Now" button is clicked. That is when I researched react routing and also headless wordpress to make all this work . But having difficulties as mentioned above in question

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

React apps need only one router component to provide a routing context to the entire app. The issue here is that `HomePageFlightContainer` is rendering another router and so when the "Search Now" link is pressed it is ***this*** router that handles the navigation action. The URL is updated and any routes ***this*** router is rendering will be updated. The main router in the `App` component isn't made aware of any of these actions.

## Solution

Remove all extraneous routers in any sub-components so `App` is rendering the one and only router and providing a single routing context to the entire application.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const HomePageFlightContainer = () => {
  return (
    <>
      ....
      <div className="col-lg-3">                    
        <Link
          to="/wordpress/search"
          className="theme-btn w-100 text-center margin-top-20px"
        >
          Search Now
        </Link>                    
      </div>
      ....
    </>
  );
}
```

The routes in `Switch` are also matched in the order they are rendered, so make sure to order the routes in the inverse order of path specificity. In other words, render *more* specific paths before *less* specific paths.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import HomePageFlightContainer from './HomePageFlightContainer';
import PageFetch from './PageFetch';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router> // <-- Only router in app!            
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/wordpress/search" component={PageFetch} />
        <Route path="/" component={HomePageFlightContainer} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Remove the `ReactDOM.render(<HomePageFlightContainer />, document.getElementById('search-flights-container'));`. `HomePageFlightContainer` is rendered as part of `App` where you are rendering it (*e.g. `ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));`*).

Comment: Currently , I am not rendering `App` anywhere. When my wordpress homepage (non react) loads , `HomePageFlightContainer` gets attached to it on the specified element. So do you mean to say bring `ReactDOM.render(<HomePageFlightContainer />, document.getElementById('search-flights-container'));` inside `App` and create a `root` element where `App` renders  on wordpress homepage plus all other changes that you suggested?

Comment: @user1207289 So you are currently only rendering the `HomePageFlightContainer` component, and nothing else? That's probably why the `Link` doesn't do anything. Yes, if you would like that "Search More" link to navigate to `"/wordpress/search"` and render `PageFetch` then the `App` component needs to be rendered somewhere in your wordpress site. When `App` renders what is the URL path of the site? I ask because if running the React app from a sub-directory you may also need to provide a [basename](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/browser-router#basename) prop to the router.

Comment: Okay , I will render `App` and get back. However , I am not sure how would I get handle of  `search-flights-container` element because it is located in wordpress homepage, which is non-react ( homepage.php) , so probably I will need to do what I am doing in `PageFetch` and render it in a react component. Is there any other way achieve this ? ( because to do what I mentioned, i will need to change a whole lot)

Comment: @user1207289 Perhaps React-Router isn't the best tool for the job then if you need to (a) navigate to *different* non-React app pages and (b) mutate the DOM to inject content. Can you edit your post to include a more complete [mcve] that shows the coupling between your wordpress site/page/pages and what you are trying to do with React?

Comment: I edited above to include more information  to provide more context for you and whoever looks at this . I am not sure of what more code I can include in here .  For now I will try to do what you have suggested and what I mentioned in comments above